# Can we eliminate the hyphens in these job descriptions?

Tags: punctuation

Can I eliminate every single hyphen in the examples below? Or do they add readability?

*Joe said, "He applied for the assistant-store-manager-trainee position.*"

*Luella said, "Victor was assigned to the organized-retail-crime-coordinator position."*

*Sam said, "Victor is now the new organized-retail-crime coordinator."*

*Bob said, "Howard applied for the store-manager position."*

Comment: This may help: http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/compadjterm.htm

Comment: I'll drop all the hyphens in those. But I'd go with "organized retail crime–related tasks" (with an n-dash).

Comment: These look better, methinks: Joe said, "He applied for the assistant store manager trainee position."

Luella said, "Victor was assigned to the organized retail crime coordinator position."

Sam said, "Victor is now the new organized retail crime coordinator."

Bob said, "Howard applied for the store manager position." Sometimes hyphens distract and obfuscate rather than clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphens are there to clarify that *assistant-store-manager-trainee* collectively modifies *position.*  Without the hyphens, the exact relationship between all of those noun adjuncts is uncertain.

If you want not to use hyphens, then I recommend saying *position of the assistant store manager trainee.*

Comment: The same, then, can be said for “the organized-retail-crime-coordinator position” and “the new organized-retail-crime coordinator”. Do you concur with the hyphen usage in both of these?

Comment: Exactly.  All of them follow the same formula.